# Random numbers come up in my calculator-like program

Tags: c

As you can see in the photo in the link, the answer comes up correctly, but the equation is wrong. please keep in mind that i am new to coding, and it might be a simple mistake

[image]

https://pastebin.com/tVuuiNic  ( LINK TO THE CODE)

```
if ((operation_type == 'A') || (operation_type == 'a'))
 {
        printf("\n\nType the numbers you wish to have added.\n\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&add_a, &add_b  );

        printf("\n\n%d + %d = %d", &add_a, &add_b, func_add(add_a,add_b) );
 }
```

Comment: BTW `scanf("%s", &operation_type);` --> `scanf("%c", &operation_type);`

Comment: And `if..if..if..if..else` --> `if..else if..else if..else if..else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the address of `add_a` and `add_b` (by using the `&`) just do this:

```
printf("\n\n%d + %d = %d", add_a, add_b, func_add(add_a,add_b) );
```